# Cannot ORDER BY date in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm retrieving data from a SQL Server CE `datetime` column, I used

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), dateHdr, 103)
```

function to get date from my `datetime` column but the problem is that it's not ordering column by date properly.

This my query:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), dateHdr, 103) 
FROM 
   tables0 
GROUP BY 
   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), dateHdr, 103) 
ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), dateHdr, 103) ASC
```

but it orders columns like this

```
01/08/2013
01/09/2013
02/08/2013
02/09/2013
```

Comment: You're sorting **by the STRING** representation of your datetime - therefore, this order **is correct**. If you want to order by the actual **date** value - use `ORDER BY dateHdr` only (not the **conversion to string!**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are using VARCHAR(10) - it is expected.
You might want to use something like below:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(DATE,BusDate,103) as Date 
FROM Table
--GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,BusDate,103) 
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Comment: Thanks @laggerok19 i just changed NVARCHAR(10) to DATETIME And it works I used DATETIME because sqlce not supports datatype DATE. . .  . . .